# Python Google Sheet API Troubleshoot - Quickstart Tutorial

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have used the following tutorial to use google sheet api:

> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?authuser=1

The steps are straight forward and I didn't need to write anything

However, when I run the command `python quickstart.py` I should have get a new google sheet tab, instead, I get this on my terminal(cmd)

```
Name, Major:
Alexandra, English
Andrew, Math
Anna, English
Becky, Art
Benjamin, English
Carl, Art
Carrie, English
Dorothy, Math
Dylan, Math
Edward, English
Ellen, Physics
Fiona, Art
John, Physics
Jonathan, Math
Joseph, English
Josephine, Math
Karen, English
Kevin, Physics
Lisa, Art
Mary, Physics
Maureen, Physics
Nick, Art
Olivia, Physics
Pamela, Math
Patrick, Art
Robert, English
Sean, Physics
Stacy, Math
Thomas, Art
Will, Math
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it should open a new Google Sheet tab?This is doing exactly what the Quickstart should; it's listing data from [the example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0).

Comment: On step 4 says:Step 4: Run the sample
Run the sample using the following command:

python quickstart.py

The sample will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.

Comment: Yes, it then goes onto say `If you are not already logged into your Google account, you will be prompted to log in. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts, you will be asked to select one account to use for the authorization.`. The window/tab is the authorisation screen. It authorises that you are running the application as you, then closes and runs the application. Everything here is working exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know what is wrong?

#### Answer:

*Nothing!*

#### More Information:

As I explained in the comment above, everything here is working as intended. The Google Sheets Python Quickstart simply lists in the terminal the information contained in [this example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0). The Window/tab it talks about opening is the authentication window which is required to run the API request as you.

#### References:

- [Google Sheets API v4 > Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?authuser=1)
- [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0)